# launch a python program on a server

Tags: python, html, cgi

**Edit: Please note that it's our first time working with a server, python, and this is my second website, so I know almost nothing about it**

We have a project and we need to put our python code on a server

the problem is, we've tried using cgi to run the code and we have two issues:

1. the program uses Tkinter, and it looks like we can't use program that use Tkinter on a server
2. when I try to run a script with a loop (our program is a timer, so it will loop), the page loads forever, it only stops loading when the program ends

can we add this python program on a server?

(also, we use a apache server)

Comment: You **DO NOT** run anything in HTML. HTML is a markup language; not a programming language! It is the presentation layer used in many Web Browsers (*plus CSS*).

Comment: we have to launch a python program in a website, should I change it to something like that?

Comment: I said we've tried using cgi, I know html isn't a programming langage

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 Do you want the Python code to run on the server or the client?

Comment: You do not run anything in a web page. There are two ways to have "dynamic content". Server-side generated resources/documents and/or combined with JS/Client requests (*i.e: AJAX*).

Comment: the client needs to launch the timer, so I thinking this I what I would want

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 That doesn't really answer my question. Where do you want Python to be executed?

Comment: FWIW; You *can* run Python code client-side in the Browser; however it is not mainstream nor available in browsers as a standard but only 3rd party libraries (*usually JS*) and various hacks and extensions.

Comment: @biffen it needs to run on the client

Comment: @JamesMills so it is possible possible but not through cgi?

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 Although possible, that is generally a bad idea. Browsers understand HTML, CSS and JavaScript (or a subset thereof). Either keep your Python code running on the server, or migrate to JavaScript. BTW, this all smells of [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem); What is it that you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: As I said; there is no easy way to run Python code in the client's brwoser; there are things like Brython and Skulpt but these are not the same as running CPython client-side. There is no CPython extension for mainstream web browsers. There is no ``<script type="text/python">``.

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 It's *technically* possible to run Python client-side but if you read between the lines I'm suggesting you do not understand Web Development at all (yet).

Comment: My original vote to close this question is quite valid; Please ask a more specific question when you've done some more research on the topic of "Web Development in Python" -- There are **many** good resources out there!

Comment: this is our first project and our teacher asked us to make a timer in a webpage and he wants the timer to be coded in python, he also keeps telling us that we need to use cgi or wiring pi

Comment: A teacher who recommends CGI is a bad teacher.

Comment: so we've been running into a wall for two months pretty much? that sucks :/

Comment: @Biffen: there's nothing wrong with CGI as a learning tool (IMHO). It may not be used much in production systems these days but it's an easy concept to wrap your head around and is simple to learn. Though, if this class started by writing a tkinter app and expecting it to work via CGI, maybe the teacher hasn't done a good job explaining how web technologies work :-\

Comment: our teacher knows has much as we do, and he saw CGI but didn't know anything about it before, but he saw you could launch python with it, so for him, that was enough

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a tkinter program on a server via CGI. Tkinter and web technologies are incompatible with each other.

Your observation about a program that runs in a loop via CGI is correct -- the program must finish in order for the CGI mechanism to work. The web server will work until that process is finished, and then return what the program returns.

Comment: so from what I've gathered, I'd have to have it run it server side, and everytime the timer updates, get the information using Javascript and update the timer on the page that way?

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: I don't know enough about your actual system to answer that.

Comment: what do you want to know?